# Foreign Key Constraint MySQL with WHERE part

Tags: mysql, database-design

Is it possible to make a foreign key constraint to prohibit relations according to a `WHERE` part?

This might sound not really straight-forward, so I'll try to explain with an example.

We've got 2 'normal' tables:

- `Person`
- `Task`

And a N:M relation between them trough:

- `Team`

One task, can have multiple tasks 'below' itself. So we make a 'tree'-order. Also within `task` is a boolean if it's a 'team': `isTeam`; For instance:

- Cleaning (`isTeam: true`)
- - Cleaning Toilets downstairs (`isTeam: false`)
- - Cleaning Toilets upstairs (`isTeam: false`)
- - Wiping first floor (`isTeam: false`)
- - Wiping second floor (`isTeam: false`)
- Dinner (`isTeam: true`)
- - Preparing food (`isTeam: false`)
- - Preparing tables (`isTeam: false`)
- - etc. (`isTeam: false`)

[image: Person is in a Team (Team is one task with subtasks]
*Image: Person is in a Team (Team is one Task with (possible) subtasks, and isTeam=true)*

The `Team` table, shows the responsible people for a certain `task`, which has sub`tasks`.
The limitation that should be applied: A `Person` can only be attached to a `Task` when the `Task`s `isTeam=true`.

Is this possible?

PS (I'm thinking, can it be done using a `view` selecting only `Tasks` which have `isTeam=true`?)

Answer (score 0):

In this model, the **[closure table](http://karwin.blogspot.ca/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html)** is used to represent a tree.

- Leaf node (**Task**) has `JobType = 'P'` (requires person)
- Other nodes have `JobType = 'T'` (requires team)
- **Team** is a group of people assigned to a **Job**.
- **Teams** are assigned only to **jobs** with `JobType = 'T'`
- A **person** may be assigned to more than one **team**.
- **Person** can be allocated only to tasks `JobType = 'P'`
- A **person** can be allocated a task only if that **person** is also member of a task-ancestor-team.

[image]